# Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field

Tags: python, django, database

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True )
    age=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Like(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    like=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

in python manage.py shell command:

```
    from database.models import Profile, Like 
    p=Profile(name='test', age=66)
    p.save()
    p.id

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-25ec00f2e4bf> in <module>
----> 1 p.id
```

But if you follow the example on www.djangoproject.com , you will get to see result of p.id is 1.

Any help will be appreciated to understand the databases as I never worked on the databases.

Comment: Because you set another field to be primary key, django won't create id field for you anymore.

Comment: Unless you have a *very* good reason - and since you're new to databases that is unlikely - you do not want to set name as the primary key. Remove that argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You model has the `primary_key` field `name`.

So if you save() your model it won't have a field called `id` as this is a default `primary_key`-field if you didn't define any.

You can access the `primary_key` by `obj.pk` (or `obj.name` in your case).

Answer (score 0):

This message is also found when primary key in database is not called "id"
It must be up to user to name primary key (particularly if database is old)
Following model definition gives error
`examination_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`
Following model definition corrects error without change in database PK
`id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column='examination_id')`
Note that django is happy with "id", mysql is free with whatever primary key is named.
In this scenario, if examination_id is used as foreign key in another table, there is further complication. Now, django want "examination_id_id" field in referenced table.
This message can be solved by defining foreign key in referred table as follows
`examination_id = models.ForeignKey(Examination, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='examination_id')`