# django app.models.VideoLibrary.DoesNotExist: VideoLibrary matching query does not exist

Tags: python, html, django

The problem is I can't type http://localhost:8000/1 to see spesific ViedoLibrary in my database. Can anyone help me to find the solution?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('main/', views.main, name='main'),
    path('create_view/', views.create_view, name='create_view'),
    path('list_view/', views.list_view, name='list_view'),
    path('<id>', views.detail_view),
]
```

views.py

```
def detail_view(request, id):
    context = {}
    context['data'] = VideoLibrary.objects.get(shop_id=id)
    return render(request, 'app/detail_view.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class VideoLibrary(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    adress = models.TextField(max_length=264, default='')
```

Also if I type id=id in views.py the next error pops up : Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: adress, attendance, equipment, films, genre, income, shop_id, shop_name, staff.

This are all my classes in models.py but there are also adress, shop_id and shop_name that are from specific model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated.

You have overriden the id field of your model that is why it won't work with id=id since the latter is actually **shop_id**. Change it accordingly and it should work.

The id error is telling you that you cannot use id as a field and giving you the list of available model fields you can use for filtering. See this answer for more details. [Error: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074120/error-cannot-resolve-keyword-id-into-field)

**Update 2**

Your views:

```
from . models import VideoLibrary

def videoLibrary(request):
    context = {}
    context['data'] = VideoLibrary.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'appname/list_view.html', context)

def detail_view(request, id):
    context = {}
    context['data'] = VideoLibrary.objects.get(shop_id=id)
    return render(request, 'appname/detail_view.html', context)
```

Your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('videos/', views.videoLibrary, name='list_view'),
    path('videos/<int:id>', views.detail_view),
]
```

Now, if you enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos` this gives you the list view. And `http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/1` gives you VideoLibrary with id 1.

Comment: this didn't help. what do you mean by saying that I don't have vidlibrary with id 0?

Comment: @unhaten see updated answer. Try adding a trailing slash too in your url path **'<int:shop_id>/'**

Comment: after editing my url path i got next error - detail_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'shop_id @fkay

Comment: @unhaten I think I know why. Your URL should be **<int:id>** not **shop_id** as I mistyped in my previous comment. The **id** part of the argument in your url should match the argument given to the view you are rendering which in your case is **id**.

Comment: @unhaten I'm taking about this section of your detail view: **def detail_view(request, id):** If this works please accept the answer.

Comment: all in all I just deleted whola database and deleted shop_id from model - it's sad that I can't use shop_id and the only thing that is left to do is to use 'id' but anyway thanks for the help @fkay

Comment: @unhaten see the updated answer with a sample code that works. As you can see it works as you intended in the first place.